# Why is my filtered query returning a tag that's supposed to be excluded?

Tags: discussion, tags, custom-filter

I have saved a filter that is supposed to show me all questions tagged [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and not tagged [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d).

This has worked for a while, but I just loaded the page and saw the following...

[image: SO search]

As you can see from the beautifully drawn orange circles, the filter is supposed to exclude questions about Unity3D, however, the very first result is tagged with that very tag.

Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: Was the tag recently added to the question? Might just be caching - when tags change that may take a minute or so to reflect in searches/filters I've noticed.

Comment: @VLAZ I suspect this is the usual issue whereby new questions get added to "update" filtered searches in real-time, even when they don't match the filter.

Comment: There's a dupe for this, for the record

Comment: Thanks, @Zoe. (Or should I call you [DenverCoder9](https://xkcd.com/979/)?) Very helpful. I've added this fact to the official record.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the comments. As far as I can see from [the revisions ](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75270875/revisions), the tag was there from when the question was first asked, but the question doesn't appear in my filtered list now, so I guess it was some sort of caching issue.

Comment: If the question was edited in the grace period, it won't show in the revisions I suspect that'd the case here, @AvrohomYisroel , considering its age in the screen shot.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel you're right. I tried it with `[html] -[css]` and on update I was getting questions also tagged with the CSS tag. It's then the same as [“X questions with new activity” showing incorrect information in windows with multiple tag filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343767).

Comment: I'm pretty sure we have an on-site dupe for this.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes. I just can find the MSE one easier.

Comment: @CodyGray It's annoying to find, because there aren't any convenient search keywords for it